# Seeking 2016 Census tract based Census Data for City of Toronto, Canada

Tags: data-request, census, data-format, canada

I have gone through all the links that have been posted over the stack exchange forum and other forums. I did go through Statistics Canada and found what I needed. But this data is in the row form and not the usual column forms. Example:

[image]

Can anyone guide me to how this can be transformed or some source where this is already transformed?

I have already tried to get access to CHASS data center and do not have anyone I know who can help me with access to it.

Source : https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/index-eng.cfm?HPA=1

Comment: Please share the direct link to the data you found that is in this format.

Comment: I have added the source link!